# Quitar espacio lateral blanco de HTML con Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay un borde blanco que no puedo quitar y no sé por qué se forma. Sólo aparece en la versión responsiva móvil.

```css
   /*/*Fuentes*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700i'; /*Header*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather'; /*Títulos*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'; /*Subtítulos*/
    
    
    body{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    
    footer{
        background-color: #B7254E;
        color: white;
    }
    
    /*Los botones dentro de una font: ;ma*/
    form > button{
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #5A1741 !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    
    /*ids*/
    
    
    #copyrights{
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    #futer{
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    #textfield{
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    #proyectos{
        background-color: #5A1741;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #id-quienes{
        color: white;
        background-color: #5A1741;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    #imagen-fondo{
        position: relative;;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    #logo{
        width: 13em;
    }
    
    #contacto-desc{
        color: #692C52;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #pasion-div{
        background-image: url("media/portada-mejor.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
        min-height: 650px;
        padding: 13px;
    
        font-size: 1.2em;
    
        /*Para que se centre el texto*/
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #pasion-div > div{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pasion-texto{
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 3em;
        /*width: 400px;*/
    }
    
    #quienes{
        background-color: #5A1741;
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    /*clases*/
    
    .ch{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #5A1741;
    }
    
    .cs{
        color: #5A1741;
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav{
        background-color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        
    }
    
    .navbar a{
        color: #B7254E !important;
    }
    
    .barraRosa-nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .barraRosa{
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .barraRosa-negra{
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #5A1741
    }
    
    .hacemos-descripciones{
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .hacemos-headers{
        color: #5A1741;
    }
    
    .fuente-merri{
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    
    .fuente-sans{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    /*Posicionar verticalmente en el centro*/   
    .vertical-align {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .form-group > input{
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <!--Boostrap jQuery-->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--Boostrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
        <!--Mi CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    
        <title> TRAMA & DRAMA | Vestuario y producción</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav id="navegacion" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">¿Qué hacemos?</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="media/logo-menu.png" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nuestros proyectos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--fin del navbar-->
    
        <!--Barra rosa única del navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-nav"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Sldeshow -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row ">
                <div id="pasion-div">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="id-quienes">
                    <center><img class="img-responsive" id="img-vestido" src="media/vestido.png" alt="Vestido"></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans" id="hacemos">
                    <h1>¿Qué hacemos?</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-renta.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de vestuario</b></p>
                    <!--<p class="hacemos-descripciones fuente-merri">Nosotros hacemos muchas cosas bien chodas</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-coordinacion.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Coordinación de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="media/icono-diseno.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Diseño de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-espacios.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de espacios para cursos</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-realizacion.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Realización</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="media/icono-mantenimiento.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Mantenimiento de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="proyectos">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                        <h1>Nuestros proyectos</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                        <p>Nos interesa que conozcas más a fondo los proyectos que llevamos a cabo en <b>Trama & Drama</b>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-1.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Diseño de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-2.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Producción y coordinación de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-3.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Renta de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img src="media/circ-4.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Servicio social</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img src="media/circ-5.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Actividades del mes</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                    <h1>Contacto</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                    <div id="contacto-desc">
                        <p>¡Nos encantan los nuevos retos! Escríbemos, llámanos o platícanos de tu proyecto.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu nombre o el nombre de la empresa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="textfield" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu mensaje">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <p class="ch">Teléfonos</p>
                <p class="cs">044 55 5601 1231</p>
                <br>
                <p class="ch">Correo eletrónico</p>
                <p class="cs">info@tramaydrama.mx</p>
                <br>
                <p class="ch">Dirección</p>
                <p class="cs">Eligio Villamar, No. 20, San Diego Churubusco. C.P: 04120, Delegación Coyoacan</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-negra"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Footer-->
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" id="futer">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/tramaydrama/?fref=ts"><img src="media/icono-fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                        <img src="media/icono-inst.png" alt="Instagram">
                        <img src="media/icono-vimeo.png" alt="vimeo">
                        <p id="copyrights">Copyright Trama & Drama 2016 &copy;. Todos los derechos reservados | Página web por <a target="_blank"
                                href="http://animanoir.com"><b>Animanoir/Claque</b></a> | Diseño por <b>Cúmulo</b>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    
        <!--Bootstrap jQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a que Bootstrap añade márgenes y paddings a algunos elementos automáticamente. En este caso, los que están provocando que se vea un hueco a la derecha de tu página son los que afectan a la clase `.container-fluid` y `.row` los cuales tienen `padding-right: 15px` y `margin-right: 15px`.

Simplemente sobrescribe en tu fichero CSS ambas clases (`.container-fluid` y `.row`) para quitar el `padding-right` y el `margin-right` respectivamente asignándoles el valor de 0.

Tendrás que tener en cuenta la **[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** de los elementos que no es más que la preferencia en el orden en el que se aplica el CSS en los elementos ya que los elementos de Bootstrap tienen más `specificity` que los de tu fichero CSS.

Para poder sobrescribir ambas clases tendrás que hacer:

```
div.row{
   margin-right: 0px;
}

div.container-fluid{
   padding-right: 0px;
}
```

en tu fichero CSS.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```css
/*/*Fuentes*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700i'; /*Header*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather'; /*Títulos*/
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'; /*Subtítulos*/
    
    
    body{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    
    footer{
        background-color: #B7254E;
        color: white;
    }
    
    /*Los botones dentro de una font: ;ma*/
    form > button{
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #5A1741 !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    
    /*ids*/
    
    
    #copyrights{
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    #futer{
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    #textfield{
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    #proyectos{
        background-color: #5A1741;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #id-quienes{
        color: white;
        background-color: #5A1741;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    #imagen-fondo{
        position: relative;;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    #logo{
        width: 13em;
    }
    
    #contacto-desc{
        color: #692C52;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #pasion-div{
        background-image: url("media/portada-mejor.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
        min-height: 650px;
        padding: 13px;
    
        font-size: 1.2em;
    
        /*Para que se centre el texto*/
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #pasion-div > div{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pasion-texto{
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 3em;
        /*width: 400px;*/
    }
    
    #quienes{
        background-color: #5A1741;
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    /*clases*/
    
    .ch{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #5A1741;
    }
    
    .cs{
        color: #5A1741;
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav{
        background-color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        
    }
    
    .navbar a{
        color: #B7254E !important;
    }
    
    .barraRosa-nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .barraRosa{
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .barraRosa-negra{
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #5A1741
    }
    
    .hacemos-descripciones{
        color: #B7254E;
    }
    
    .hacemos-headers{
        color: #5A1741;
    }
    
    .fuente-merri{
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    
    .fuente-sans{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    /*Posicionar verticalmente en el centro*/   
    .vertical-align {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .form-group > input{
        width: 50%;
    }

    div.row{
      margin-right: 0px;
    }

    div.container-fluid{
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <!--Boostrap jQuery-->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--Boostrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
        <!--Mi CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    
        <title> TRAMA & DRAMA | Vestuario y producción</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav id="navegacion" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">¿Qué hacemos?</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="media/logo-menu.png" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nuestros proyectos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--fin del navbar-->
    
        <!--Barra rosa única del navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-nav"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Sldeshow -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row ">
                <div id="pasion-div">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="id-quienes">
                    <center><img class="img-responsive" id="img-vestido" src="media/vestido.png" alt="Vestido"></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans" id="hacemos">
                    <h1>¿Qué hacemos?</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-renta.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de vestuario</b></p>
                    <!--<p class="hacemos-descripciones fuente-merri">Nosotros hacemos muchas cosas bien chodas</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-coordinacion.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Coordinación de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="media/icono-diseno.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Diseño de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-espacios.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de espacios para cursos</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/icono-realizacion.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Realización</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="media/icono-mantenimiento.png" alt="">
                    <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Mantenimiento de vestuario</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="proyectos">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                        <h1>Nuestros proyectos</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                        <p>Nos interesa que conozcas más a fondo los proyectos que llevamos a cabo en <b>Trama & Drama</b>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-1.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Diseño de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-2.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Producción y coordinación de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img src="media/circ-3.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Renta de vestuario</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img src="media/circ-4.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Servicio social</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img src="media/circ-5.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Actividades del mes</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                    <h1>Contacto</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                    <div id="contacto-desc">
                        <p>¡Nos encantan los nuevos retos! Escríbemos, llámanos o platícanos de tu proyecto.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu nombre o el nombre de la empresa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="textfield" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu mensaje">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
                <p class="ch">Teléfonos</p>
                <p class="cs">044 55 5601 1231</p>
                <br>
                <p class="ch">Correo eletrónico</p>
                <p class="cs">info@tramaydrama.mx</p>
                <br>
                <p class="ch">Dirección</p>
                <p class="cs">Eligio Villamar, No. 20, San Diego Churubusco. C.P: 04120, Delegación Coyoacan</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!--Barra rosa-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-negra"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--Footer-->
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row fuente-sans">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" id="futer">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/tramaydrama/?fref=ts"><img src="media/icono-fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                        <img src="media/icono-inst.png" alt="Instagram">
                        <img src="media/icono-vimeo.png" alt="vimeo">
                        <p id="copyrights">Copyright Trama & Drama 2016 &copy;. Todos los derechos reservados | Página web por <a target="_blank"
                                href="http://animanoir.com"><b>Animanoir/Claque</b></a> | Diseño por <b>Cúmulo</b>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    
        <!--Bootstrap jQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Solucionó mi problema; se ve bien en dispositivos móviles.

Comment: Total, la solución es esta

Answer (score 4):

A diferencia de lo que menciona **Error404**

Yo sugiero no modificar nada del Core de Bootstrap, lo que pasa es que el maquetado está mal. Digo si vamos a utilizar un framework el chiste es utilizarlo de forma correcta.

Tu error es utilizar más de un "container", ya que solo debe haber uno.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12>

        <!-- Tambien puede haber rows dentro de las Col -->
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solo ten cuidado, pues la clase "Row" abarca toda la Fila, sin respetar margenes...

En fin para probar esta teoria solo deja 1 div con class `container`.

Comment: Tendré en cuenta tu solución. Sin embargo la de Error404 funcionó.