# Espacio en blanco a la derecha Bootstrap [Solo en Vista MÓVIL]

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Buenas gente, nuevamente con un problema más...
Casi tengo terminada mi web, pero hay algo que me tiene loco y desconcertado.
En ordenador se ve bien, pero solo en dispositivos móviles se ve una franja blanca a la derecha (un espacio en blanco).

En Firefox cuando uso el Responsive Design mode (en ordenador) tambien se ve perfecta en el tamaño móvil (320x480), pero al verla realmente con mi móvil, aparece.

He probado todas las soluciones que he visto tanto aquí StackOverflow Español como en Inglés, pero ninguna ha acertado correctamente.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085785/white-space-right-side-of-bootstrap-website

[Quitar espacio lateral blanco de HTML con Bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38483/quitar-espacio-lateral-blanco-de-html-con-bootstrap)

He probado con **overflow: hidden;** y funciona solo en el tamaño grande, pero en versión móvil sigue apareciendo...

Otra cosa que me ha sucedido al dar con una de las tantas soluciones que leí por internet es que quizás me quitaba el espacio y todo iba perfecto, peeero mi NAV dejaba de ser sticky.

En fin, dejo el link de mi web completa para ver si pueden descubrir en que me estoy equivocando...
https://sbguardavidas.000webhostapp.com/

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Salu2!

Comment: Muchas gracias por resolver el problema, la herramienta me fue de utilidad para ver el problema en mi caso. de igual manera mi problema era porque los row´s sobrepasaban el margen tanto como el navbar y mi footer(con background), lo resolvi quitando los paddings de los lados. Esto no me afectó para nada en la visualización de la nav o el footer y en mobile se ve excelente. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuevamente me autorespondo.
Despues de luchar y luchar, el problema lo tenía en la clase que le agregaba a cada CONTAINER.
Yo le agregaba un background junto con un **padding: 100px 0px;**
Esto hacía entrar en "conflicto" el padding de la clase CONTAINER junto con esta clase mía que tenía.

Yo tenia esto:

```
<div class="container-fluid galeria">
   Contenido
</div>
```

y de CSS:

```
.galeria{
    padding: 100px 0;
    /*Más código CSS*/
}
```

Esto hacía que la clase Container de Bootstrap cambie su padding.
Lo que hice fue poner por separado, y ya no tocar el padding-left y padding-right

```
.galeria{
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        /*Más código CSS*/
}
```

Y problema resuelto... una tontería que me costó demasiado descubrir.

Aprovecho tambien a dejar algo interesante que encontré para buscar estos problemas cuando no encontramos que es lo que nos esta generando el espacio en blanco. Un debug CSS para visualizar mejor que es lo que lo está generando.

http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/

Saludos y gracias!